# What does constructor.prototype.property do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
var x = { foo: "A" };
x.constructor.prototype.foo = "B";
var y = {};
```

After running this code x.foo returns "A" which is understood. But y.foo returns "B" even if y is an empty object. I'm interested to know what does x.constructor.prototype.foo actually do?

Thanks for everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.constructor` refers to `Object` (since all object literals have reference to `Object` assigned to their `constructor` predefined property).

`Object.prototype` is given a property `foo` and assigned value of "B".

`y` is object literal, thus it's internal `[[Prototype]]` property (available as `__proto__` in some engines) refers to `Object.prototype`.

Due to JavaScripts prototypal inheritance, every time when object's property is requested, and this object does not contain the property, engine looks upward the prototype chain.

Thus when accessing `y.foo` - since `y` has no property named `foo` - you are accessing `y.[[Prototype]].foo` which is exactly `Object.prototype.foo`.

Comment: Thanks. Clean and crisp answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `constructor` property of an object points to the constructor function that constructed the object. Your `x` variable is an object-literal, which was thus constructed by the `Object()` constructor function. Thus, accessing `x.constructor.prototype` is the same as accessing `Object.prototype`.

All constructor functions have a `prototype` property which forms part of the prototype chain. Basically, when your try to access a property of any object when that property is *not* actually defined on the object, then the JavaScript engine follows the prototype chain backwards looking to see if that property is defined on a prototype within the chain.

Because your `y` variable is *also* an object-literal, and thus was also constructed by `Object()`, when you try to access `y.foo`, since the `foo` property does *not* exist on `y`, the prototype chain search is commenced, which immediately hits `Object.prototype.foo`, which, as you know, has been assigned to `"B"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's
>   prototype

in other words, all objects will now have a `foo` property, as you've added `foo` as a property on the Object prototype, and it's not the same as the `foo` property you added to `x`, you just did

```
var x = { foo: "A" };
Object.prototype.foo = "B"; // all objects from now on inherits this
var y = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you did

```
var x = {foo: 'A'};
```

js has created an object with constructor Object(), You can verify it by typing

```
x.constructor
```

it will write function Object () {} in console.

now you are going further and accessing prototype of Object class and added 'foo' property in that.

At this point your Object class has a new property called 'foo'.

Now you have created a new object and referenced it with y. now y is created with Object constructor which contains 'foo' property.

Here prototype inheritance also kicks in. As you don't have any property in y it starts looking for 'foo' in the prototype hierarchy and 'foo' is found at the very and when it reaches Object in the hierarchy.

If you would have written:

```
var y = {foo: 'C'};
```

y.foo will give you output as 'C'